# Is it possible to get infected while entering a mispelled url?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, troubleshooting, virus, malware

I accidentally mispelled hotmail, so instead of that I entered hotmoil(dot)com. I did closed fast my browser when I noticed but is it possible to be infected? I saw no new downloads and I am using chrome with ublock origin basic filters aswell as bitdefender. I did already scan my computer and found luckily nothing but this is eating up my mind in worry that there may have been an stealth download that may have given me an infected machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a website loads, it can always infect you. Make sure you scan for both viruses and malware.

Its not a guarantee though.

For a malicious thing to happen, one of the following must be true:

- The websites downloads a file and you open it.
- The browser you used is not updated to the latest version and has a vulnerability that is being exploited
- The websitemakers found an exploit that has not yet been fixed in the latest version of your browser (unlikely, but possible)
- You have allowed certain actions to not be blocked, and the website succesfully installed a browser extension that contains malicious code.

In any case, a good malware scanner should find all of these if you are indeed infected. Keep in mind that a virusscanner does not necessarily find malware. I would scan with malware bytes, just to be sure.

Comment: I have not tried scanning with malwarebyted because Bitdefender is not liking it. I did however scan with adwcleaner and hitman pro but nothing got found. From what I know my browser is up to date too and no other/unwanted Extension. I guess I am safe then?

Comment: I trust hitman pro too. If it didn't find anything, you're safe.

Comment: Thank you. I will trust you because everybody else was just telling me that "this is not a thing" meaning "you can't get malware etc that way

Comment: Chances are slim, but they are possible. Most common source for this problem is when your software is not up-to-date or when you have set a setting that inadvertently allows a script to do malicious things. For example, you have a browser extension that does not work, but you found out, if you run your browser as administrator, then it works, but not realising that this opens a whole can of worms of options for attackers.

Comment: The only extensions I have are from my AV and ublock origin (that I don't really know how to use) other than that, I don't have any other extensions and my computer had the newest windows updates aswell up to date AV database and up to date chrome. So the chance something might really have happened is slim to none in this case. Right?

Comment: Yes. I just added the extensions as a possible way to get an infection, not as something that you would have.